# How to get all keys except one in Mongo Db aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have aggregation request to Mongo Db collection.

```
dataStore.FirstCollection.aggregate([
'$lookup': {
      'from': 'SecondCollection',
       ...
    },
'$match': ...//some filter for SecondCollection
])
```

Now I need to response back all values only from FirstCollection. In SQl it would be:

```
select FirstCollection.* from ...
```

I know that I can use "project": and mention all existing keys, but I don't like this approach...

Comment: [`$unset`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$unset` [projection stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/).

This is different from the `$unset` [update operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "SecondCollection",
      "as": "sc",
      ...
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": ...
  },
  {
    "$unset": "sc"
  }
]
```